# Help with align environment and split

Tags: align, matrices

I would like some direction as to how to get my equations to align like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
{\mathbf{u}} & = H^{-1}({\mathbf{P}}_{T}-B) \\
& = {}\begin{split}\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}{}
&\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}\right.\\
& \left. - \begin{bmatrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
        \end{bmatrix} \vphantom{(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1}}\right)
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I have looked at the other posts and also tried using `\vphantom` and `{}`, but could not get the correct output.  Can you assist me in getting the correct output?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better look out you can obtain with use `aligned` instead of `split. Deficiency of it use is position of equation number. It is aligned with the first line in aligned enivironment:

[image]

I code below I removed all unnecessary things. For adjusting brackets I (by trial) put `\;` before it in the first line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u} & = H^{-1}(\mathbf{P}_{T}-B) &\\
           & = \begin{aligned}[t]\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
                            \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
               &\left(\;\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                \end{bmatrix}\right.\\
               &\left. - \begin{bmatrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                            \end{bmatrix} 
         \right)
                \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Maybe will be better to move second line to left than the first one to the right (what erase distance between parenthesis and square bracket):

```
               &\left(\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                \end{bmatrix}\right.\\
               &\kern-0.8ex\left. - \begin{bmatrix}% <-- here is adjusted position of bracket
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                            \end{bmatrix} 
                \right)
```

**Edit (2):** And one more alternative, based on Guho comment:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u} & = H^{-1}(\mathbf{P}_{T}-B) &\\
           & = \begin{aligned}[t]\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1} \\
\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
                            \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
               \bigg(&\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + \delta r_{3v} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                \end{bmatrix}\\
                   - &\begin{bmatrix}
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2}\sin\theta_{1} \\
         (L_{1} + r_{3})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2}\cos\theta_{1}
                            \end{bmatrix} 
                \bigg)
                \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

With manually settings of size parenthesis (\big, \bigg, \Big .... etc) ypo can put ampersand between parenthesis and rest of equations. With this you don't care for manually moving lines as before, however, you need to select the size of parenthesis.

Comment: Hello @Zarko, can you post your code please?  Thanks.

Comment: I try several times ... but have some strange problem. Now I see, that it is finally appear in answer (at least I can see it).

Comment: @Zarko: Another option: You could manually set the parenthesis size (`\bigg(` and `\bigg)`), then place the `&` right before `\begin{bmatrix}`.

Comment: @Guho, yes, this simplify manual adjusting alignment of second line in `aligned˙ environment, however you need some how guess the size parenthesis.I will add this possibilities. Thank you to remind me on this.